# Ruby cannot load such file - but can load similar files in the same directory

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

There are many "cannot load such file" questions around but I can't find one that fits my scenario.

I am building a gem, using the normal [bundler method](http://howistart.org/posts/ruby/1). Development and testing has been completed to a satisfactory point. All the actual files are in the /lib/my_gem folder. Then I built a CLI, called /lib/my_gem/cli.rb. Like all my other files in that folder, they are all in the Module MyGem.

I changed the file /lib/my_gem to read like this. Names changed to protect the innocent.

```
require "my_gem/version"
require "my_gem/file1"
require "my_gem/file2"
require "my_gem/file3"
require "my_gem/file4"
require "my_gem/file5"
require "my_gem/file6"
require "my_gem/cli"

module MyGem
  # Nothing
end
```

Then I built the gem using `rake build`, and installed the gem using `gem install`. However when I then put `require 'my_gem'` into another ruby file, and run it, I get....

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kerel_require.rb:55 in 'require' cannot load such file - my_gem/cli (LoadError)
```

But - if I comment out line 8 in the above code segment, it all works just fine. I can't understand why `require` works fine for the first 7 files but not the 8th?

Comment: How does your `gemspec` file look like?

Comment: spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject do |f|
    f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  end
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"] (plus the usual dependencies, and metadat)

Comment: Maybe your file is not committed to git? Is it listed with `git ls-files`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it, thanks! I hadn't made a commit since adding cli.rb. This whole project was designed as a learning experience with regards to using Ruby "properly" so... another useful thing learned - about how Ruby & git are quite intertwined, which I'd heard about but only appreciate now I've come across an issue. Can you type it up as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Glad to hear! Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files must be whitelisted in the `gemspec` file.

A common practice is to defer to git for the list of files.

You commented that your gemspec looks like this

```
spec.files = git ls-files -z.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
spec.bindir = "exe" 
spec.executables = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) } 
spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

Maybe your file is not committed to git? Is it listed with `git ls-files`?

Comment: Yes that's it... I hadn't done a commit since writing cli.rb.